# Javascript/JQuery dispay form input on webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm fairly new to Javascript/JQuery. I'm trying to write an app that takes text input through a form, applies a function to it, and then displays the processed text. I'd rather avoid sending the input to the server, to avoid validation headaches. I can get the text to display in an alert box, but I can't work out how to display it on the webpage itself.

```
function do_stuff(my_string) {
    //...
    return my_processed_string;
}

$(':submit').click(function() {
    $('#text_input').each(function() {
        my_string = $(this).val();
        my_processed_string = do_stuff(my_string);
        alert(my_processed_string);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Any ideas how to modify this so that my_processed_string appears on the webpage instead of in an alert box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purposes of this answer I'm going to assume you want to make my_processed_string appear at the end of a div with an id of "test".

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <div id="test"></div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Replace the alert line in your example with the following:

```
$("#test").append(my_processed_string);
```

Does this produce the result you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
function do_stuff(my_string) {
    return $(selector).append('<input type="text" value="' + my_string + '" />');
}

$(':submit').click(function() {
    $('#text_input').each(function() {
        my_string = $(this).val();
        return do_stuff(my_string);
    });
    //return false;
});
```